# Pango.Fontdescription doesn't work in raspbian OS (pygobject)

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject, pango

i want to change font of `Gtk.Entry` by using pango (`entry.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Sans Bold 20'))`), it works well at windows but doesn't works at raspbian and has no effect

Comment: Do you have this font installed on your raspbian?

Comment: yes installed before